# Can I write a test that succeeds if and only if a statement does not compile?

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to prevent clients of my class from doing something stupid. To that end, I have used the type system, and made my class only accept specific types as input. Consider the following example (Not real code, I've left off things like virtual destructors for the sake of example):

```
class MyDataChunk
{
    //Look Ma! Implementation!
};

class Sink;

class Source
{
    virtual void Run() = 0;
    Sink *next_;
    void SetNext(Sink *next)
    {
        next_ = next;
    }
};

class Sink
{
    virtual void GiveMeAChunk(const MyDataChunk& data)
    {
        //Impl
    };
};

class In
{
    virtual void Run
    {
        //Impl
    }
};

class Out
{
};

//Note how filter and sorter have the same declaration. Concrete classes
//will inherit from them. The seperate names are there to ensure only
//that some idiot doesn't go in and put in a filter where someone expects
//a sorter, etc.

class Filter : public Source, public Sink
{
    //Drop objects from the chain-of-command pattern that don't match a particular
    //criterion.
};

class Sorter : public Source, public Sink
{
    //Sorts inputs to outputs. There are different sorters because someone might
    //want to sort by filename, size, date, etc...
};

class MyClass
{
    In i;
    Out o;
    Filter f;
    Sorter s;
public:
    //Functions to set i, o, f, and s
    void Execute()
    {
        i.SetNext(f);
        f.SetNext(s);
        s.SetNext(o);
        i.Run();
    }
};
```

What I don't want is for somebody to come back later and go, "Hey, look! Sorter and Filter have the same signature. I can make a common one that does both!", thus breaking the semantic difference `MyClass` requires.

Is this a common kind of requirement, and if so, how might I implement a test for it?

Comment: Could you clarify precisely which statement should not compile here?

Comment: @MSalters: All of what is above should compile correctly. What should not compile would be if someone tried to use a "sorter" where they should have used a "filter". The filter must run before the sorter because theres no reason to sort data which is going to be thrown out.

Comment: So basically Filter::SetNext() should accept a Sorter argument, but Sorter::SetNext() should not accept a Filter argument? Sounds trivial to me, I don't see what the title has to do with that.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes. What I don't want is for someone to come back later, see that "Sorter" and "Filter" have the same signature, use an automatic refactoring tool to make them one type, and break that semantic check.

Comment: It sounds like you would be better off throwing out the whole idea that `Filter` and `Sorter` are the same type of object.  After all, it doesn't make sense to sort objects twice.  Separate things that can be chained from things that can't, and add them to your structure separately.  Then, in your `Run` routine, just run your single Sorter after any of your Filters.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: They are different. I want to be able to write a "test" that fails later if someone tries to put them together.

Comment: I still don't see how it is possible to write an compile-time test when (as you state) the signatures are identical to the point that a refactoring tool can't distinguish between them. Either they're interchangable or they're not.

Comment: @MSalters: All it takes is to have a cast between the filter and the sorter pointer types. If someone refactors the class to be the same, the cast will compile. In the current design, it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest clarification the problem is simple:

```
void foo(Filter*);
void foo(Sorter*);
template<typename T> void test() {
   foo((T*)NULL);
}
```

If anyone passes a class that's both a Filter and a Sorter, the overload resolution is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. If a statement doesn't compile (ie. is not valid ISO C++), the compiler is no longer under the obligation to create an executable.

There is one famous exception, which even has an abbreviation: SFINAE, or Substitution Failure Is Not An Error. Roughly speaking, in a number of situation (such as overload resolution) the compiler will instantiate some templates implicitly, to consider the results. It would be very annoying if the compiler would try an instantiation that failed to compile, and then stopped the entire compilation process. Therefore, it will silently discard instantiation errors in such cases.

This SFINAE mechanism can be exploited to determine certain attributes at compile time. Consider this:

```
template<typename T> class Foo() {
  static char test(T);
  static int test(...);
  static const size_t result = sizeof(test(0));
};
```

Now, if the expression `T(0)` compiles, i.e. if 0 can be converted to a T, then Foo::result is sizeof(char)==1 and else Foo::result is sizeof(int).

Comment: This might be workable. I need to check only a single statement, and I can check Foo::result with an assertion.... +1. Will checkmark if I get something that works.

Answer (score 2):

Why wait until runtime? Compile time checks ([static asserts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html), for example) can let the offending code fail to compile.

But to answer your question, I believe no - you cannot do this unless you're running the compiler as part of your test.

But, again, look into compile time assertions or [concept checks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm). There's no reason to wait until test time to see these errors.

Comment: Compile time assertions would be fine if I wanted to assert that a statement **would** compile. However, asserting that something does **not** compile is more difficult. I don't particularly care if it's compile time or runtime (I'd assume it'd **have** to be compile time though)

Comment: If you want to disallow certain things from compiling then the right thing to do is _make_ them fail to compile by introducing various compile time checks (e.g. like concept checks). Doing this in run time is too late.

Comment: Lavie: The problem there is that I need the rest of the project to compile without failing.

Answer (score 0):

To test for expected compile time failure, you'll need to be running the tests in some kind of framework with automated building. The framework calls the compiler to build from source, check the compile return code for success/failure against expected and then run the resulting tests .exe if it were runtime tests.

I know such features exist in Boost's regression test, although I haven't actually studied how its implemented. Maybe you can have a look there for examples / ideas.